# undefined reference to 'MainScene::createScene()' collect2: error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I got the following error but there should be no problem in my code. Since I had declared the createScene method. It would be great if there are some tips or hints that could lead to solving this problem!

```
AppDelegate.cpp:82: error: undefined reference to 'MainScene::createScene()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

AppDelegate.cpp:82: This is where the error is occuring

```
// create a scene. it's an autorelease object
auto scene = MainScene::createScene();
```

This is MainScene.cpp

```
#include "MainScene.h"

USING_NS_CC; //Means using cocos2d

MainScene::MainScene() {

}

MainScene::~MainScene() {

}

Scene* MainScene::createScene() {

   auto scene = Scene::create();
   auto layer = MainScene::create();

   scene->addChild(layer);
   return scene;
}

bool init() {
    if (!Layer::init()) {
        return false;
    }
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto size = director->getWinSize();
    auto background = Sprite::create("background.png");
    background->setPosition(Vec2(size.width/2.0, size.height / 2.0));
    this->addChild(background);

    //initialize process
    return true;
}
```

This is MainScene.h

```
class MainScene: public cocos2d::Layer
{
protected:
    MainScene();
    virtual ~MainScene();
    bool init() override;

public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
    CREATE_FUNC(MainScene);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget to define `init()` method of your `MainScene` class

```
bool init() {
    ...
    ...
}
```

change it to

```
bool MainScene::init(){
    ...
    ...  
}
```